# type Queue does not take parameters Queue<Integer> q = new ArrayDeque<>();

Tags: java, algorithm, data-structures, tree, tree-traversal

```
  public static void levelorder(Noden root){
           if(root == null){
               return;
           }
          Queue<Noden> q = new ArrayDeque<>();
           q.add(root);
           q.add(null);
           while(!q.isEmpty()){
               Noden curr = q.remove();
               if(curr==null)
               {
                   System.out.println();
               if(q.isEmpty()){
                   break;
               }else{
                   q.add(null);
               }
               }else{
                   System.out.println(curr.data+" ");
                   if(curr.left!=null){
                       q.add(curr.left);
                   }
                   if(curr.right!=null){
                       q.add(curr.right);
                   }
               }
           }
       }
   }
```

and when i use priorityqueue at the place of queue  throwing nullpointer error

i try to trverse a tree using leveltraversal algorithm
but i stuck!!

Comment: Sounds like you've got the wrong `Queue`.

Comment: There's no `Queue<Integer>` in the code you've posted.